# Value of $y''(0)$ when $2y=\tan(x+y)$

Tags: calculus

Question:

> If $2y=\tan\left(x+y\right)$ and $y=f(x)$, what's the value of $y^{''}\left(0\right)$

My progress is:

> $2y'=\sec^2(x+y)(1+y')$
>
> $\frac{2y'}{1+y'} =\sec^2\left(x+y\right)\:$
>
> $\frac{2y''(1+y')-2y'\cdot y''}{(1+y')^2}=2\sec(x+y)\cdot \tan(x+y)\cdot \sec(x+y)(1+y')$
>
> $\frac{2y''(1+y')-2y'\cdot y''}{(1+y')^3}=2y\cdot \sec^2(x+y)$

**My problem is What is $y$ equal to at $x = 0$?**

**The answer I got from my book is $y(0)=0$.Is that right?**

Comment: When $x=0$, you’ll get $2y = \tan y$. Pretty much by inspection $y=0$ is a solution, aside from the fact that there are infinitely many solutions

Comment: Oh, I see. My textbook is wrong.@Tavish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
Substitute $$ \sec^2 (x+y)=(1+4y^2)$$

From here
$$\frac{2y'}{1+y^{'}}\:=\:sec^2\left(x+y\right)\:=(1+4y^2)$$
$$\implies y'=\frac{1+4y^2}{1-4y^2}.....(1)$$
It will give $y'(0)$
$$\frac{2y'}{1+y'}=(1+4y^2)$$

Comment: Good idea！But what's the next? I still can't figure out what y is?

Comment: Check out the answer,

Comment: $y(0)=1/2\cdot tan(y)$?

Comment: No mate,$ y(0)=1/2\cdot tan(y(0))$